# long running queries web application (azure) solution

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

We have an ASP MVC 3.0 application that reads data from the db using Entity framework (all on Azure). We have several long running queries (optimization has been done) and we want to make sure that the solution is scalable and prevent thread starvation.

We looked at async controllers and using I/O completion ports to run the query (using BeginExecute instead of the usual EF). However, async is hard to debug and increases the complexity of the code.

The proposed solution is as follows:

1. The web server (web role) gets a request that involves a long running query (example customer segmentation)
2. It enters the request information into a table along with the relevant parameters and returns thereby allowing the  thread to process other requests.
3. We set a flag in the db that enables the UI to state that the query is in progress whenever a refresh to the page is done.
4. A worker role constantly queries this table and as soon as it finds this entry processes the long running query (customer segmentation) and updates the original customer table with the results.

In this case an immediate return of status to the users is not necessary. Users can check back within a couple of minutes to see if their request has been worked on. Instead of the table we were planning to use Azure Queues (but I guess Azure queues cannot notify a worker role so a db table will do just fine). Is this a workable solution. Are there any pitfalls to doing it this way?

Answer (score 1):

While Windows Azure Storage queues don't give you a notification after a message has been processed, you could implement that yourself (perhaps with Windows Azure Storage tables). The nice part about queues: They handle concurrency and failed attempts.

For instance: If you have 2 worker instances processing messages off the same queue, every time a queue message is read, the message goes invisible in the queue, for an amount of time you specify. While invisible, only the worker instance that read the message has it. If that instance finishes processing, it can just delete the queue message (and update your notification table). If it *fails* (maybe due to the role instance crashing), the message re-appears on the queue after the invisibility timeout expires. Going one step further: Let's say it's simply a bad message that causes your code to crash every time. You can check the dequeue count before processing the message. If it's greater than, say, 2, simply store the message in a dead-letter table and inspect it manually.

One caveat with queues: The queue messages need to be *idempotent* operations (that is, they can be processed at least once, and the results should have the exact same side-effects each time).

If you go with a table instead of a queue, you'll need to deal with scaling (multiple threads or role instances processing the table), and dead-letter handling.

Comment: David - thanks a bunch for clarifying. We will go with queues. But on the whole is the approach we are planning to take a workable solution (and one thats not frowned upon :)) -  with worker roles taking on the long running queries and not making the web roles async?

Answer (score 1):

This depends. If your worker role does nothing other than delegating the heavy work to a SQL database, it seems a waste of resource and your money. Using a web role with async requests allows you to reduce the cost. If it is needed to do a heavy work in the worker role itself, then it is a good approach.

You can also use AJAX or web socket. Start the database query, and return the response immediately. The client can either poll the web role to see if a query has finished (if you use HTTP), or the web role can notify the client directly (if you use web socket).

Comment: Ming - the worker role needs to do some heavy processing and also communicate with third party web services send email sms etc. Just curious - when you say start the query and return response immediately do i need to do it with a BeginExecute right. I am assuming I cant use EF.  Any pointers towards an example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What I meant was: You start a background thread to working with database (it can either be sync or async). Your main method that processes the client request returns a response immediately. Do not wait until the background thread finishes.